# Was Homelander the first Supe?

Tags: the-boys-2019, the-boys

As we learn late in Season 1 of *The Boys*...

> The "Supes" were created by the Vought Company using a substance called Compound V.

We also learn that Homelander was...

> raised in a lab under the supervision of Dr. Vogelbaum.

From the conversation with Dr. Vogelbaum...

> he states that raising a super without their mother was a mistake. Which considering Starlight and Rebecca Butcher's son both being raised with mothers he seems to have learned from the mistake.

So considering the "lesson learned' on Supes growing up it struck me that Homelander might have been the first. Is their any confirmation of this?

(Willing to accept answers from the comic series as well, but preference and acceptance would be for the show)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Show Answer**

The first hero is indeed Stormfront, the same as the comics, however:

> Stormfront is now a woman who was married to Vought and first successful recipient of Compound V. It is also evident that she and Vought were devout members of the Nazi Party.

In an exchange in S02E06 *"The Bloody Doors Off"* with Homelander, Stormfront explains

> [Stormfront] I will never lie to you again. I will tell you everything. Starting with this.
>  
>  [Stormfront opens a chest and pulls out photographs]
>  
>  [Homelander] Your grandmother?
>  
>  [Stormfront] My daughter. Chloe. She died of Alzheimer's a few years ago.
>  
>  [Homelander] How old are you?
>  
>  [Stormfront] I was born in 1919. In Berlin.
>  
>  [Homelander] Is that you with...
>  
>  [Stormfront] Heinrich Himmler. He was a lovely dancer. And that's Goebbels. And... the most important man in the room...
>  
>  [Homelander] Frederick Vought
>  
>  [Stormfront] He gave me the first successful V injection. He taught me everything. And the we fell in love and he gave me a daughter. He made me, and his genius made you. Frederick Didn't care about all the fans or stardom or any of that shallow bullshit. We are in a war for the culture. The other races are grinding us down and taking what is rightfully our, but we can fight back. With an army of supermen millions strong. Because that is Vought's true destiny.

Answer (score 5):

Comic book answer: The first Supe was called Stormfront. He was created in Nazi laboratory by Dr Vogelbaum and his DNA was used as blueprint Vought improved on when creating Homelander. Dr. Vogelbaum was forced to create Supes for Vought as a condition so he can run away from war and survive. Dr Vogelbaum is the original creator of compound V.

He took Stormfront (who was a member of Hitler Youth then) with him when he ran away. It was near the end of World War II. The previous heroes that were created before Homelander by Vought experimenting with injecting Compound V into people are Team Payback. The original incarnation of the team were all killed, along with the soldiers they were supposed to aid, in the sole military operation they took part in (The Boys, [Issue 52](https://readcomiconline.to/Comic/The-Boys/Issue-52) and Issue 53). They used powers unwisely in the middle of the war. Vought tried to sell them to military as the next superweapon but were forced to go back to the drawing board after the failure. They worked on improving the formula after that and spent billions and trillions of dollars on it, before finally creating Homelander and his team.

I don't know about tv show answer.

Comment: It appears in the TV show that Stormfront is still the first supe, although switched to a woman. And given her age (referenced in a flashback) and the repeated indications of white supremacy in her behaviour, it's quite probable she has a similar backstory.

Answer (score 4):

From the comics: No, Homelander was not the first superhero.

The first successful superhuman was Stormfront, a member of the Hitler Youth, when Vogelbaum worked with the Nazis.

I believe that Stormfront was the source of Homelander's DNA though.